# Absolute imports using alias not working in ubuntu. Works in windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, babeljs, absolute-path

So I'm using an absolute import statement in react and it works well in Windows system. When same project is started in Ubuntu, I get

> Can't resolve './components/base/navBar/NavBar' in '/home/<user_name>/Files/Projects/<project_name>/src'

Below is the babel plugin config (.babelrc),

```
[
    "babel-plugin-root-import",
    {
        "paths": [
            {
                "rootPathPrefix": "~",
                "rootPathSuffix": "./"
            },
            {
                "rootPathPrefix": "@src",
                "rootPathSuffix": "src"
            },
            {
                "rootPathPrefix": "@Component",
                "rootPathSuffix": "src/components"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

and this is the import statement I'm using in ./src/App.js

> import Navbar from "@Component/base/navBar/NavBar";

---

and this is the rule for js file in webpack,

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
        },
    },
}
```

---

Works in windows. Does not work in ubuntu.
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://dev.to/mr_frontend/absolute-imports-in-create-react-app-3ge8). Describes well how to use absolute imports in React.

Comment: Tried it. Did not work. There are other ways to achieve this such as using resolve.alias in webpack. But I need to know why the above code works in windows but does not work in ubuntu.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.